# Hero Component customization

Tags: apex, lightning, community, lightning-experience

Is it possible to customize the content/button on Hero component in community builder based on guest user and logged in user?

Any solution with respect to Builder--->themes--->CSS overrides---> Can something be done here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible to override the css in Hero Component.
Here are steps how you can archive that:
Go to your community builder and inspect the element in the template that which you want override and get its css class like below picture-
[image]

After that go to themes--->CSS overrides
[image]

Add the css for that element. for example -
.ctaButtons a{ background-color: blueviolet !important;}
[image]
**Note:-** Added css should be with **!important** that help to override the css from current.

See the result button color is changed.
[image]

Comment: Thanks .But my question was whether we can hide/show the button or content of hero component based on logged in user and guest user.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think it's not possible that things in the hero component, but we can customize the colors, logo, and font styles of the hero component based on logged-in users and guest users by using branding sets.

Comment: Thank you. It is possible to show different content in hero component by creating a theme layout and overriding that on the page . we would need to create two variation s of the page to show it to logged -in and guest users.